# SQL injection Attack in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube, sql-injection

I am trying to achieve one of the scenario using java code. I am writing some bad code to analyse it over sonarqube.

I tried to test "SQL queries should not be vulnerable to injection attacks" from https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/SonarSecurity/RSPEC-3649.
Below is the code that i am trying to analyse,

```
package group;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;
import javax.naming.*;

public class SonarDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream o = System.out; //NOSONAR

        String pass = args[0];//request.getParameter("pass");
        String user = args[1];
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" + user + "' AND pass = '" + pass + "'"; // Unsafe
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", user);
        connectionProps.put("password", pass);
        java.sql.Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:localhost:sql1;create=true",connectionProps);
            java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            java.sql.ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            Files.exists(Paths.get("/home/", user));

            String filter = "(&(uid=" + user + ")(userPassword=" + pass + "))"; // Unsafe

            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext();
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search("ou=system", filter, new SearchControls());

        } catch (Exception e){
            o.println("Exception");
        }

    }

}
```

But there is some Issue in code where sonarqube isn't able to pick up this code and show there is an issue with injection attack.

How to modify this code to create some SQL injection attack so that my sonarqube can able to show this error on dashboard?

In short- Modifying above code to create injection attack as as mentioned here https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/SonarSecurity/RSPEC-3649

Comment: Would it not work if you set password to something like `"pass; DROP TABLE Users; --"`

Comment: Or you could set `pass` to `' OR '1' = '1` and select will return all records.
Not sure that `statement.executeQuery()` will execute two queries (select and delete) at once

Comment: Depending on your database, replace `--` with `#`.

Comment: SQL injection attacks come from using some form of unsanitised input with SQL queries, not from just using string concatenation.  Prepared queries are just one way of sanitising the input, probably the easiest, but not the only way.

Comment: Thanks @Andonaeus and @ Ivan. This is just like a test case I really dont need to use database. But I am just mimicking something to show how SQL inject attack happens

Comment: The code you are testing is indeed vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Sonarqube cannot detect your SQL injection scenario, that doesn't mean that it is safe.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman I agree that this is doing some injection attact. Now I am trying modify this code so that sonar can able to pickit up and show issue as i mentioned in question. Thanks!

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, Indeed, there's an old quote from 1969 by Edsger Dijsktra: "Testing shows the presence, not the absence of bugs." You're right that a tool like Sonarqube isn't necessarily able to find 100% of SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Exactly!  None of the program analysis tools is perfect. Each of them has a very precisely defined threat model (at least all the good ones). If you step outside of it - Boom!

Answer (score 2):

> User provided data such as URL parameters should always be considered
>   as untrusted and tainted.

AFAIK runtime args are not recognized as input from the user. To reproduce the issue try taking *user* and *pass* from the URL parameters of a request.

```
public boolean authenticate(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, java.sql.Connection connection) throws SQLException {
  String user = request.getParameter("user");
  String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
}
```

Comment: I will give a try

Answer (score -2):

In this particular line

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" + user + "' AND pass = '" + pass + "'"; // Unsafe
```

instead of using `+` to concat string ,use `StringBuilder` and its append method to concat string which will avoid SQL injection attack.

Comment: OP is not trying to *prevent* a SQL injection attack using this code;  quite the opposite;  they are *creating* vulnerable code on purpose, in a controlled environment, so they can verify the soundness of a scanning tool (sonarqube).

Comment: oops i dint read properly, but then if that is the case then above could should give SQL injection attack error in sonar.

Comment: That's exactly the point of the OP's post;  why is this vulnerable code not being identifed as vulnerable?  They ask  *"But there is some Issue in code where sonarqube isn't able to pick up this code and show there is an issue with injection attack"*?

Comment: I don't see how `StringBuilder` would prevent an injection attack; it doesn't behave differently than `+`, it's just more efficient.